# How to disable previous month button itself (not dates) in AngularUI date-picker control?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui, angular-ui-datepicker

Want to disable/hide previous month button , when angularUI date-picker showing current month and enable/show previous month button, when angularUI date-picker not showing the current month or future months. 

Ex:- Current Month is June
if date-picker showing June dates, it should disable/hide previous month button.
if date-picker showing July or future months(aug,sep..) dates, it should enable/show previous month button

Comment: Have you checked out moment.js?  It makes working with dates much more simple.

Comment: I am not doing anything with date manipulation here. Just i need to disable a button.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: There's nothing in there.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/R5ZNpCMCpIhbYstpjvvl?p=preview updated link here

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, from what I can see there isn't really a way with Angular to do this, so I came up with a hacky jQuery way:

```
//Disable the previous month button with monthCount at 0
$(".calendar button[ng-click='move(-1)']").addClass("disabled").attr("disabled","disabled");

var monthCount = 0; 

//Decrease monthCount if previous month button isn't already disabled
$(".calendar button[ng-click='move(-1)']").not("disabled").on('click',function(){
     monthCount--;

     //if monthCount hits 0, disable it
     if(monthCount < 1){
        $(this).addClass("disabled").attr("disabled","disabled");
     }
})

//Increase monthCount on next month button click                  
$(".calendar button[ng-click='move(1)']").on('click',function(){
     monthCount++;

     //enable previous month button as long as monthCount is greater than 0
     if(monthCount > 0){
        $(".calendar button[ng-click='move(-1)']").removeClass("disabled").removeAttr("disabled");
     }
})
```

Answer is too late for OP, but hopefully this saves someone else some time in the future.